# How can you create a new user with GCP full admin and not billing access?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-billing

It seems reasonable to want to grant an administrator access to create any and all resources without being able to pull / change / delete billing info.

I seem to recall there was a role something like "project owner" that had full admin but couldn't control billing (and maybe couldn't create new projects).
Does anyone know of a role like that? It has been a while since I set up a new GCP account. I've searched around a bit and can't immediately lay hands on the information.

[The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) is not super helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In Google Cloud, there is no single role that grants permissions to everything. Some roles do have enough power to support granting themselves more roles.

There are multiple admin-level roles and this evolves as Google creates and modifies services. You will need to review the services that you are using and then grant roles to that identity.

The Organization Administrator has the power to grant itself and any other identity any role. However, this role itself has few permissions.

The Owner account has the power to grant itself and any other identity in the same project any role. The Owner role has a vast number of permissions but does not have all of them. The Owner must grant itself permissions for some resource types.

Note: Only a billing account admin can grant permissions to the billing account.  That privilege is separate from Google Cloud permissions. Billing accounts are not part of Google Cloud and have their own management structure.

Comment: Perhaps I'm asking the wrong question.
What is the preferred process for adding new GCP admins?

Comment: @joar -GCP admin for what? Review the services and select the admin roles for the services you want to be an admin of. If you want to be an admin of everything, add all admin roles. As new services are released, sometimes you will need to review the roles for that service and add that to the identity. Note there is overlap among many of the roles, but the point is there is **no** role with admin privilege for everything.